# setwindowtitle is not replicated in ubuntu side tool bar PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer, fbs

I am trying to create an application using PyQt5, FBS, and QtDesigner

My app works as I expected

My problem is while I move the cursor over my app icon in ubuntu sidebar, its hover says `unknown`

I using the following line in my code

```
app.setWindowTitle("my first app")
```

This title is not replicated in ubuntu left sidebar icon hover

Answer (score 0):

To change the application name, use the `setApplicationName` function:

```py
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName("My first app")
main_window = ...
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```